# Get last few revision SHA on a branch

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to get the few latest revision SHA without checking out any code.

I know you can get the list if you have a local copy with git log

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H" --first-parent origin/master | head -10
```

and you can get only the latest revision with git ls-remote

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:foo/foo.git master
```

But I need to get a list of the last 10 revisions, not just the last.

Can anyone help?

Comment: For what purpose? I ask because you can get this sort of information via the Github API, that might be more suitable.

Comment: I basically need to get the latest code revision that passes certain tests -- unfortunately, there's no way to get the latest successful rev from the test directly. I can only go down the list one by one and check if that revision passes or not, until I find one that does.

Github API sounds like a good alternative -- I've never used it before, but will 
 start exploring that option

Comment: If you're searching for which commit broke the build, look into [`git-bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect).

Comment: First of all - I agree with Schwem that you probably should use bisect rather than a linear search.  If you know it's in the last 10 commits, bisect will take at most 4 test runs with an expected count of 2.9, whereas linear search will take at most 10 test runs with an expected count of 5.5.  If there's a chance you won't have found it after 10 and might have to keep searching... the bigger the search set, the more you want to use `bisect`.  Second... to run your tests, you'll have to fetch the code, so why are you opposed to cloning (which handles all the remote transport at once)?

Answer (score 2):

> *I basically need to get the latest code revision that passes certain tests -- unfortunately, there's no way to get the latest successful rev from the test directly. I can only go down the list one by one and check if that revision passes or not, until I find one that does.*

The tool you're looking for is [`git-bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect). It does a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) to find which commit broke the tests. Any test you give it. It's much more efficient than going through them one by one.

Clone the repository and then...

```
$ git bisect start
$ git bisect bad           # the current version is bad
$ git bisect good v1.2.3   # v1.2.3 was good
```

It will then check out a commit between those two. You can run your tests and tell it if it's good or bad with `git bisect bad` or `git bisect good`. It will then move on to the next commit in its binary search. Eventually it will narrow the failure down to one commit. This generally takes `log(n)` tries. So if there are 100 commits to search it will find it in about 10 tries.

You can automate the process with `git bisect run <command>`. It will run the `command` on each commit and use the exit status to determine if it's good or bad.

This, btw, is why it's important to avoid making commits which fail tests.

---

Generally Git goesn't like to operate via remotes. It's just not built for that. Simplest thing to do is clone the repository and use `git log`. Most repositories are very small. If they aren't, that's going to cause all sorts of problems and you should look into [`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to fix that.

You can do a shallow clone and fetch just the last 10 commits with `git clone --depth=10`. That will save you some time, but it probably isn't worth it unless the repository is enormous.

---

If it's on Github, you can use the [Github V3 API to request the tip of the branch](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/) and then walk backwards using the `parents` link. For example...

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/evalEmpire/perl5i/branches/master
{
  "name": "master",
  "commit": {
    "sha": "aa1124b89f38eed793e2b9f2d2b2ba5d80a27a20",
    ...
    "parents": [
      {
        "sha": "d100dd2a118c425c730c17e395371e2cd84b43a3",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/evalEmpire/perl5i/commits/d100dd2a118c425c730c17e395371e2cd84b43a3",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i/commit/d100dd2a118c425c730c17e395371e2cd84b43a3"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
```

There's the new [Github API v4 GraphQL](https://developer.github.com/v4/) API which allows you to craft queries. With that you can conceivably get all 10 commits in one query, but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.

git-bisect doesn't really work either because the test is run on another system (teamcity) and takes more work to report back the result to git.

The solution I finally took was to use github API to get the list of recent commits and parse the first 10 revisions

`https://api.github.com/repos/foo/foo/commits?sha=master`